# Return Gridview Checkbox boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've racked my brains on trying to access the ID column of a gridview where a user selects a checkbox:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUserFiles" runat="server">
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox  ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

The gridview columns are chkSelect (checkbox), Id, fileName, CreateDate

When a user checks a checkbox, and presses a button, i want to receive the "id" column value.

Here is my code for the button:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvUserFiles.Rows)
            {
                var test1 = row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect");
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)(row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect"));
                //chk = (CheckBox)(rowItem.Cells[0].FindControl("chk1"));  
                if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
                {
                    bool test = true;

                }
            }
```

The cb.checked always is returned false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Checkboxes being always unchecked can be a problem of DataBinding. Be sure you are not DataBinding the `GridView` before the button click event is called. Sometimes people stick the DataBinding on the `Page_load` event and then it keeps DataBinding on every `PostBack`. As it is called before the button click, it can make direct influence.
When the `GridView` is DataBound you lose all the state that came from the page.

If you Databind the `GridView` on the `Page_load`, wrap it verifying `!IsPostBack`:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    gvUserFiles.DataSource = data;
    gvUserFiles.DataBind();
}
```

If that is not your case, you can try verifying the checked property based on the `Request.Form` values:

```
protected void button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvUserFiles.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");

        if (cb != null)
        {
            bool ckbChecked = Request.Form[cb.UniqueID] == "on";

            if (ckbChecked)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Checked` value of a `CheckBox` is sent by the browser as the value `"on"`. And if it is not checked in the browser, nothing goes on the request.

Comment: Ok, I am definitely data binding on page_load.  How should I data bind the gridview then?

Comment: Ok, wrapped the 

`gvResults.DataSource = UserResults;
gvResults.DataBind();`

in a `if(!Page.PostBack)` and it worked.  You are awesome!

Comment: @Tim Johnson, Sorry, i should have posted the right way on the answer, i just didn't know it was the problem. You may accept it as the answer if it suits your needs. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using datakey like this

Add Datakey to your gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUserFiles" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id">
```

and get it server side like this

```
string value = Convert.ToString(this.gvUserFiles.DataKeys[rowIndex]["Id"]);
```