# FindControl doesn't find control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am setting up a gridview so that I can select several events and add their EventID's to a comma delimited string.   This is going to be a subscription service, so I need to know which events the user wants to be subscribed to.

I used a template field to add a Checkbox that I could use it as an indicator of which event items I wanted.

so the gridview looks like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    PageSize="15" 
    ViewStateMode="Enabled" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="Purple">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="eventSelected" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventID" HeaderText="EventID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EventID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventName" HeaderText="EventName" SortExpression="EventName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BaseTypeKey" HeaderText="BaseTypeKey" SortExpression="BaseTypeKey" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BaseTypeDesc" HeaderText="BaseTypeDesc" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BaseTypeDesc" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and the information is populating quite nicely.

my code to retrieve the selected items should be simple but isn't functioning yet.

```
private string GetCheckedEvents()
{
    List<string> outputString = new List<string>();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("eventSelected");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            outputString.Add(row.FindControl("EventID").ToString());
        }
    }
    return string.Join(",", outputString);
}
```

when debugging the code though, the CheckBox is set correctly and enters into the if statement but then hits the single line of code and comes up with

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in EventEmailerConfiguration.dll but was not handled in user code

trying to navigate inside the object explorer that is given by the Debugger is a PITA to say the least.

Am I not traversing to the right location?

How do I extract the information that I need?

Comment: When does `GetCheckedEvents()` gets called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return Gridview Checkbox boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186546/return-gridview-checkbox-boolean)

Comment: @DennisR in a button click event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot find a `BoundField` since it's not a real control. You have to use  `row.Cells[index].Text`:

```
outputString.Add(row.Cells[1].Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim's suggestion should work but if `EventID` is the primary key for the dataset you are binding to the gridview then you could use the  [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the gridview to store the key values and access where ever you need. Then your `GetCheckedEvents ()` function will become,

```
 private string GetCheckedEvents()
    {
        List<string> outputString = new List<string>();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
          if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
          {
              CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("eventSelected");
              if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
              {
                  long eventID= long.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["EventID"].ToString());
                  outputString.Add(eventID);
              }
          }
        }
        return string.Join(",", outputString);
    }
```

and the gridview definition

```
 <asp:GridView .... DataKeyNames = "EventID" ...  </asp:GridView>
```